# obtain partition size without root access

Tags: partitions

On my device, I can obtain a list of existing partitions by executing `ls -al /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name` via ADB. But I found no way to obtain the size of each partition without root powers: `cat /proc/partitions`, `blockdev --getsize64 <device>`, `cat /sys/class/block/sda3/size`, `cat /proc/diskstats` – all of them give me a `Permission denied`; `lsblk -no SIZE <device>` gives me a "not found" (no `lsblk` obviously). Things like `df` or `mount` are not helpful in this context as they only apply to mounted partitions, and I need sizes from partitions **not** currently mounted.

Are there any methods I might have missed and which might work on a non-rooted device?

<sup>(the device in question runs Android 10, but I'm interested in all general solutions at least for recent devices, hence no version tag)</sup>